# Necesito imprimir JFrame en java eclipse (hice una factura y quiero imprimir esa factura en la impresora), aquí dejo el botón

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Print");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Podrias detallar mas tu pregunta, a que te refieres exactamente con "imprimir".

Comment: Te invito a revisar [ask], ademas de editar y agregar mas detalles a la pregunta.

Comment: mira ahora bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir una factura tienes que generar un código mucho mas extenso,
 con el diseño de tu factura, te invito a que mires como imprimir reportes, ireports es un editor visual de reportes, con el que podrás generar tu factura fácilmente.

Comment: Donde puedo ver ?